# Can I edit a question to change its meaning?

Tags: discussion

If I have a question that I asked a long time ago (Over 2 or 3 months old), and it already has an answer that I have marked as the accepted answer, can I slightly modify the question so that the meaning of the question might differ? The reason I would want to do this is because I have another question that is similar to the first question. However, I think that if I asked it by itself, it could be seen as a duplicate of the first question. This second question could be added onto the first question and it would still be part of the same question.
I am referencing [This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21459/whats-the-difference-between-bokeh-and-gaussian-blur). I would like to modify it to ask "what's the difference between bokeh, gaussian blur, and blurriness"

Comment: I would suggest referencing your question and discuss the changes you are proposing specifically. Generally speaking, I'd say you should not change the *meaning* of a question after the fact. But I would only be guessing if that applies to your case specifically.

Answer (score 5):

If the meaning is different, then ask another question.  Generally, we're pretty careful about only closing a question as duplicate if one of the answers in the previous question directly answers the new question, so it is unlikely to be a problem.

Conversely, editing an old question to change the meaning removes useful information from the site and risks not being noticed as it is an old question.